# Kafka cluster on EC2

Tags: apache-kafka

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicServ
```

I am trying to run 3 node kafka cluster on a single ec2 instance.. but getting this.

Can anyone please help

Thanks

Comment: Is your Zookeeper running?

Comment: Hey @RobinMoffatt it was resolved. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you maybe post as an answer what the issue was, to help other people?

Comment: There were multiple issues.. I am writing complete steps for it and will share on this thread.

Comment: Hey @RobinMoffatt are you familiar with hivemq kafka extension? I need a help in it.

Comment: @AleenaRehman Can you kindly update on how you resolved this issue, I am also facing the same issue. Kindly update.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING

 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)